# UICollectionView Datasource methods do not get called

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, datasource

I am refactoring my `ViewControllers` and one of them contains a `collectionView` but now the DataSource is not getting called anymore.

**My ViewController:**

```
class CoinPageVC: UIViewController, DependencyInjectionVC, Storyboarded {

    lazy var mainView: CoinPageV = {
        let v = CoinPageV()
        v.collectionView.delegate = self
        return v
    }()

    var coin: Coin!
    var selectedBase: String!
    var viewContainer: [UIView]!

    var collectionViewViewDataSource: CollectionViewCoinPageDatasource?


    func injectDependencys(dependency: CoinPageDependency) {
        self.coin = dependency.coin
        self.selectedBase = dependency.base
        self.viewContainer = dependency.views
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionViewViewDataSource = CollectionViewCoinPageDatasource(data: viewContainer)
        self.mainView.collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewViewDataSource
        self.mainView.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
extension CoinPageVC: SetMainView {}

extension CoinPageVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width:CGFloat = collectionView.bounds.width
        let height:CGFloat = collectionView.bounds.height
        // - (tabBarHeight + menuBar.frame.height + heightNavigationBarTop)
        let output = Utility.shared.CGSizeMake(width, height)
        return output
    }

    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let index = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
        mainView.menuBar.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    }
}
```

**My Datasource class:**

```
class CollectionViewCoinPageDatasource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let data: [UIView]

    init(data: [UIView]){
        self.data = data
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
        return data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //let outputCell: UICollectionViewCell
        let row = indexPath.item
        let outputCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifier.coinPageCollectionViewOverviewCell.rawValue, for:indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellView
        outputCell.view = data[row]
        return outputCell
    }
}
```

**My collectionView setup:**

```
lazy var  collectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.register(CollectionViewCellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifier.coinPageCollectionViewOverviewCell.rawValue)
    if let flowLayout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }
    cv.backgroundColor = .green
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    //cv.backgroundColor = .blue

    return cv
}()
```

What did I miss?
I set up the datasource and also connect it to the datasource of the `collectionView`, but the methods do not get called.

Comment: Is the collectionView visible? I meant you set its frame to 0,0,0,0, is has it a "real frame" when you reload it?

Comment: yes I set up the constraints later on, I did not change anything to CoinPageV so that should not be the Problem

Comment: But when `self.mainView.collectionView.reloadData()` is called what's its current frame at that point?

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem I forgot to call setMainView() from the SetMainView protocol.

Answer (score -1):

```
lazy var  collectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.register(CollectionViewCellView.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Identifier.coinPageCollectionViewOverviewCell.rawValue)
    if let flowLayout = cv.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }
    cv.backgroundColor = .green
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    //cv.backgroundColor = .blue



    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()
```

Comment: Thats my collectionView inside the CoinPageV, "collectionView" is part of CoinPageV, I add the datasource here:         self.mainView.collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewViewDataSource

Answer (score -1):

because collecitonview height is zero

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).